# how to move an CCSpirit object in zigzag way to upside in cocos2d programming?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am doing as below with CCSpirit object as below

```
id actionMove2 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:4 position:ccp(40, 520)];

id actionMoveDone2 = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self    selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];

[Sobject runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove2, actionMoveDone2, nil]];
```

where Sobject is an CCSpirite on object in cocos2d, 
but now I want to move the same object in zigzag format to upside, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move your sprite along the polyline then just combine CCMoveTo actions into sequence.

If you want some smooth trajectory - combine CCBezierTo into sequence.

If you want some complex custom move create a CCSprite subclass and add some method as

```
-(void) myMethod(float dt)
```

Then schedule it and make in this method any transformation you want

Comment: means there is no build-in function for zidzag movement, and i have to make ma own class?

Comment: @Veer: yes, you have to make your own